# How to loop through an array, find elements from a mongoose collection to return a new array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, foreach

I have an array of object id's.

I need to loop through the elements of this array and perform the below operation.

```
var commObj;
commentArray.forEach(
    (comment)=>{
        if(comment.parents.length>1){
            Comment.findById(comment.parents[comment.parents.length-2]).exec(
                (err, foundComment)=>{
                    if(!err){
                        commObj = foundComment;
                        if(! commObj.replies){
                            commObj.replies =[];
                        }
                        commObj.replies.push(comment);
                    }else{
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
        }
    }
)
return res.status(200).json(commObj);
```

I am seeing that the commObj variable is returned as undefined. I can see that this is happening because of the async nature of the action that I am doing inside the forEach loop. However, I could not figure out a way to return commObj.

Comment: As you mentioned - It might not be because of *async nature of the action* ! Did you try to print `comment.parents[comment.parents.length-2]` & `foundComment` ? cause `.findById` will return `null` if no matching doc exists !!

Comment: How could `id` be an integer and not a hexa string? `comment.parents[comment.parents.length-2]`

Comment: @whoami yes, I tried printing both and they are not null. I am able to see the result for both of them.

Comment: @gazdagergo comment.parents[comment.parents.length-2] is a mongoose object id.

Comment: @SudharsanPrabu : Is it a string or of type `ObjectId()` ?

Comment: @whoami It is of type ObjectId.

Comment: @SudharsanPrabu : I guess it might be string value of `ObjectId()` cause `.findById()` will only take a valid string as input..

Comment: i printed the typeof which stated object. I think mongoose converts object to string automatically, because I am able to see the result fetched correctly as foundComment.

Answer (score 0):

In deed, forEach is not usable for loop async operations. Use for-of instead like:

```
var commObj;

for (let comment of commentArray) {
  if(comment.parents.length>1){
...
```